# Xbox live email address

Tags: xbox-360

I can't remember my email address for my xbox live account but I know my password for a fact. What should I do? Please help me if you can. /:

Comment: contact Microsoft? we cant do anything to help you remember your email address.

Comment: I tried it didn't work .

Answer (score 2):

Your easiest solution would be to contact Microsoft at (US): 1-800-469-9269 or [request a call back.](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/request-call?service=my-account&category=xbox-live-membership&issue=Other&ccfissue=&ewt=5&navlistpath=NavigationList&preferedLocale=en-US&siteId=xbox-prod&)